# Activate-Deactivate submit button in a form

Tags: button, backbone.js

I made a registration form using backbone.js, CoffeeScript and jquery.
I am trying to disable the submit button after 1 click (so that it doesn't fire events again and again) , i also want that button get active again when i fill fields of my form.. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code that runs the event (hopefully in the events delegate routine of your view) all you have to do is tell JQuery to disable the button

```
$("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
```

Then when you need to re-enable it

```
$("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Just call the appropriate calls when required.

Comment: This won't disable form submission from 'enter'

Answer (score 0):

seems there is no enable/disable property. maybe you could use the “silent” option to keep the “change” event from triggering?

or just create a validation routine and call it from the event i.e.

(pseudo code)

```
BUTTON EVENT FIRED
IF IsValid() then
'do something
else
'do something else
end if

func IsValid() as boolean
' check to see if the form is ready to submit i.e. required fields are valid
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#my_button"): This uses a jQuery selector to target an element with the ID "my_button". You should replace "my_button" with the actual ID of your button.

.attr("disabled", false): This sets the "disabled" attribute of the selected element to false, which means the button is enabled. The attr function allows you to get or set attributes of an HTML element.

.removeClass('disabled'): This removes the "disabled" class from the button. This is often used to change the visual appearance of a button when it transitions from being disabled to enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks alot @Bryan and @max ..
I have done it as :

```
enable_button: ->  
  $("#my_button").attr("disabled", false).removeClass('disabled')
```

I am also changing the color of button on enable/disable.